# How can I save my custom width to a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm working on a width changer. I use jQuery for this, but I've a problem. The idea is that when the user clicks the button, the width changes instantly. I'd like to save the user's selection in a cookie, but I don't know how I can do.

Current jQuery code:

```
$(function()
{
  $(".width-changer").on("click", function(e)
  {
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("custom-width");
  });
});
```

I use this plugin for the cookie:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

It is in my index.html.

The wrapper class is my global width.

Comment: "the button" "the width" What button? The width of what? Get into the habit of being precise and clear!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7qh4pj Look the demo.

Comment: No, write a coherent question with all the relevant details contained within it. This is a Q&A repository, not a personalised helpdesk or forum.

Comment: Look here: http://thoughtscenter.com/test/ What I need, it is to save the user's selection when he clicks the button for that, during the next visit, the width is saved. I'd would like to do that with cookies.

Comment: You didn't read what I wrote did you

Comment: Why do you find complications? There is nothing complicated in my request. You don't understand just what I asked, so don't reply please.

Comment: Oh, brother.... You have a fundamental misunderstanding of what this website is. Read the help centre and take the tour. Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution worked for me in i.explorer & Firefox, for chrome i think you should to enable cookies :

```
$(function()
{
    if ($.cookie('custom_width')=='true') { //add true to this condition
        $(".wrapper").addClass("custom-width");
    };

  $(".width-changer").on("click", function(e)
  {
    $(".wrapper").toggleClass("custom-width");

    if($(".wrapper").hasClass("custom-width"))
        $.cookie('custom_width', 'true');
    else
        $.cookie('custom_width', 'false');

  });
});
```

Hope that this solution help you.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work, but not totally. When I click on the button, the width is saved when I refresh the page, but when I click on the button again to return to the default width and I refresh the page, the former width is recovering.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is the same:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Neither Method Tested:

```
$(".width-changer").on("click", function (e) {
    var control = $(".wrapper");
    control.toggleClass("custom-width");
    if (control.hasClass("custom-width")) {
        $.cookie('WidthOption', 'custom-width');
    }
    else {
        $.cookie('WidthOption', '');
    }
});
```

OR

```
 $(".width-changer").on("click", function (e) {
        var control = $(".wrapper");
        control.toggleClass("custom-width");

        $.cookie('WidthOption', control.width());
    });
```

Retreive the cookie value:

```
    $.cookie('WidthOption');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local Storage
[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)