# Can't set cookie from inside function [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

When I put try to set cookie from out of function it works fine but if I put cookie inside of function it not working...

Here is what I try to do:

```
$(function(){
      $("#on").click(function() {
           $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
       });
});
```

html

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" id="on">On</a>
```

Comment: Is your button by any chance dynamically created after the page is loaded?

Comment: Normally that should work, try to show cookie in console directly after creation inside function.
Add this line : 
`console.log($.cookie('the_cookie'))`, and tell me what is the result.

Comment: Not created dynamically... Here is what I get in console: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` it looks like `$.cookie` just can be called outside function

Comment: No, in this post : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305393/how-can-i-save-my-custom-width-to-a-cookie/31305684?noredirect=1#comment50601372_31305684 ] (Cookie inside function) , you can see in correct answer that we use it inside the click event function.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake I loaded jQuery lib after jquery.cookie.js but need before...